# When Using MUI Button: TypeError: Cannot read property 'borderRadius' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Screen from './components/Screen/Screen';
import Button from './components/Button/Button';
import { MuiThemeProvider, createMuiTheme } from 'material-ui/styles';
import pink from '@material-ui/core/colors/pink';

const buttonTheme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: '#2dff46',
    },
    secondary: pink,
  }
});


class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <MuiThemeProvider theme={buttonTheme}>
      <Screen>
        <div>Hello</div>
        <Button variant='contained' color='primary'>
          GO
        </Button>
      </Screen>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I am simply trying to create a button with some custom colors (theme). It will work without "theme={buttonTheme}" but of course it uses the default. I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'borderRadius' of undefined
styles
node_modules/@material-ui/core/Button/Button.js:41
  38 | minWidth: 64,
  39 | minHeight: 36,
  40 | padding: '8px 16px',
> 41 | borderRadius: theme.shape.borderRadius,
  42 | color: theme.palette.text.primary,
  43 | transition: theme.transitions.create(['background-color', 'box-shadow', 'border'], {
  44 |   duration: theme.transitions.duration.short
```

thanks!!

Comment: What does your Button component look like? And should this line be `import { MuiThemeProvider, createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';` ?

Comment: @PatrickDillon YOU ARE CORRECT!!! I got that import from another example. I guess it is outdated or something. Thanks for the response.

Comment: @PatrickDillon.. You're my SAVIOR ..spent 3 hours to fix this...BOTTOMS UP..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in an earlier comment, the import statement was incorrect.
This:

```
import { MuiThemeProvider, createMuiTheme } from 'material-ui/styles';
```

Should be this:

```
import { MuiThemeProvider, createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
```

Answer (score 1):

In case anybody else has a similar issue. The above answer never fixed my problem but pointed me in the correct direction I had to add

```css
shape: {
 borderRadius: 16
}
```

To my material ui theme.

Answer (score 0):

So this is a two step thing for you, I'm not across Material-ui, but the main issue is that the theme-shape isn't being provided to your button component.

The first thing i'd do is debug and log out the `buttonTheme` constant to confirm that it is matching the theme defined in https://material-ui.com/customization/default-theme/ with the addition of your overrides.

If you can see the the `shape: border-radius: 4` portion then you know it is an issue with MuiProvider, but from looking at your code it seems to be correct.

Let me know what the theme looks like (Update your question) and we can work from there

Comment: I had thought so too, but in the tutorials/examples I was using there was no mention of having to specify the shape. It turns out the import I had gotten from an example was incorrect. Thanks for your response though!

Comment: Oh so obvious! always the way XD