# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'borderRadius') in MUI react

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

i was implementing a navbar with a search bar component. i styled my search component with MUI styled from `@emotion/styled` from MUI. and gave search component a `borderRadius: theme.shape.borderRadius`.

**but its showing the following error**

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'borderRadius')
```

here is my Search component style

```
const Search = styled('div')(({ theme }) => ({
  backgroundColor: 'white',
  padding: '0 10px',
  borderRadius: theme.shape.borderRadius,
}));
```

but when i gave `borderRadius: 10px` it work fine. something with the theme that i passed.
please help me with the code

also refered following stackoverflow questions but nothing fixed me all those question were outdated i am using `MUI 5`

[When Using MUI Button: TypeError: Cannot read property 'borderRadius' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52508383/when-using-mui-button-typeerror-cannot-read-property-borderradius-of-undefin)

[borderRadius not working when use Material UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56323735/borderradius-not-working-when-use-material-ui)

Answer (score 0):

i  solved the problem by creating a my own theme. and passed the theme as a prop to
`ThemeProvider` and wrapped all the children inside `ThemeProvider` in `app.js`

```
  import { ThemeProvider } from "@mui/material";
  import {theme} from './theme'

    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
          <Box>
            <Navbar />
          </Box>
        </ThemeProvider>
```

created my custom theme using createTheme from MUI

```
export const theme = createTheme({
  palette:{
    primary:{
      main: "#1760a5",
      light: "skyblue"
    },
    secondary:{
      main: '#15c630',
    },
    otherColor:{
      main:"#999"
    }
  }
});
```